# Pygame images move with rotation

Tags: python, rotation, pygame

I am still having problems with rotation (see my previous question) so to solve them i took the problem out of the context of my game, to see if i could get it to rotate without the confusion of everything else i was trying to do.
The problem I have now is that the image rotates, but it also flies off screen at the same time. I do not have any move commands, it is only supposed to rotate in place. 
why is this happening?

here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

size = width , height = 400 , 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

car = pygame.image.load("Car3.png").convert()
carRect = car.get_rect()
carRect = carRect.move(200 , 200)

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           running = False

    car = pygame.transform.rotozoom(car ,30  , 1)

    screen.blit(car , carRect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

note:
the reason i am using rotozoom is that i read that problems can arise from the image automatically resizing when it is rotated.

Comment: I don't have personal experience with `Pygame.transform.rotozoom`, however I would suspect that it might be rotating around _the_ origin, rather than the surface's origin.  If this is the case, the surface would be rotated around wherever the point (0,0) is at in the "world".  Try temporarily moving the surface object to the world origin, performing the rotozoom operation, and then moving it back.

Answer (score 0):

What are you planning to achieve by using these two lines here?

```
carRect = car.get_rect()
carRect = carRect.move(200 , 200)
```

Why do you call the Rect.move function here?

Your problem is probably, that the blit is done with the top left corner. I don't know the measurements of your image, but could it be that it's "rotating" out of the window because the top left corner shifts during the rotation process?

It's a bit late here, otherwise I'd look up the documentaion myself and give you a more elaborate answer. But till then: When rotating images, I'd go by the center of the image for placing it, and not by its top left corner. Can be done either way, I find it easier using the center.